# figref with subfigure and parentheses

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, subfig

I use IEEEtran with subfigure and `\figref`.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \subfloat[Foo.\label{fig:test-foo}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{foo}} \\
        \subfloat[Bar.\label{fig:test-bar}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{bar}}
    \caption{Foo and Bar.}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

When I use `which is shown in \figref{fig:test-foo}.` I get:

*which is shown in Fig. 16a.*

However, I want to see

*which is shown in Fig. 16(a).*

I have tried everything I could find, including variations of

```
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

The options in the first don't seem to have any effect with `figref`. When I use `\renewcommand`, `figref` works but the captions in the figure itself get double parantheses, e.g. *((a)) Foo.*

Comment: You can use `\ref{fig:test}\subref{fig:test-foo}`.  I've been searching through subfig code to see where the sub@label format is defined, but no joy so far.  I did find`\captionsetup[subrefformat=subsimple]` in the subfig code, but that would require loading the subcaption package, making subfig redundant.

Comment: Yes I can do `Fig.~\ref{fig:test}\subref{fig:test-foo}` but that makes the entire nice latex method of having macros useless! When I want to change "Fig." to "Figure" I have to manually catch all the occurences and on top I have to reference the figure AND the subfigure. If I use `\figref{fig:test-foo}` it works as expected "Fig. 1a" except without the parantheses. Is there really no universal way to make it "Fig. 1(a)" with `\figref`?

Comment: Is this \figref from the commath package?  If so you might want to say "I use IEEEtran with subfig and commath."

Comment: I deleted my answer because I think it did not correspond to what you are really doing. The problem is that you did not provide a MWE, so we can't know from what package does this `\figref` command come from. Please update to a MWE.

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subfig}            % <---
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}   % <---
\newcommand\figref[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}               % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\subfloat[Foo.\label{fig:test-foo}]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}} \\
\subfloat[Bar.\label{fig:test-bar}]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Foo and Bar.}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\ldots which is shown in \figref{fig:test}, particularly in \figref{fig:test-foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]