# Two Images top and bottom with a common caption and separate representation

Tags: captions, includegraphics

I want to align two images top and bottom. The images should have the representation (a) and (b), and there should be a caption on the bottom ex: fig 1.1 (a)figure_caption1 (b) figure_caption2.

I have tried multiple things but unfortunately could not achieve it.
This is the following code i have been trying

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{pic1.png}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:Ng1} 
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{pic2.png}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}

\caption[Two pictures]{(a)caption here. (b)caption here}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share with us what you tried. I'm sure people here can then help make them work.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477957/figref-with-subfigure-and-parentheses

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i have edited my question with the code that i have tried

Comment: This is not very  helpful, You should provide code (copy from your editor), not its image.  Preferable in form of small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. It seems that your errors are not caused by `figure`.

Comment: @Zarko thank you for the suggestions, I have edited the question accordingly. for the code written in the question, I am receiving the error accordingly in the attached picture

Comment: @bella_pa Your code fragment works fine if I guess a couple of packages. Please provide a small test document which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should start with a documentclass and the necessary packages.

Comment: @bella_pa, you should provide complete small document with your figure, which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. As I already mentioned in previous comment, your errors are not caused by showed code fragment.